# Making the HTML list to a checkbox tree with the plugin jstree

Tags: javascript, html, plugin-option-tree

I would like to make a tree with checkboxes with the jstree plugin.
I know I am really close to the solution. I linked everything right, but on my page it only showes the HTML list without tree and checkboxes.
Does anyone know what I am missing out, so that the checkboxes work.

```
<title> Hi all</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().
'/js/jstree/dist/themes/default/style.min.css';?>" />

<div id="data">
<ul>
<li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three
        <ul>
        <li>Bike</li>
        <li>Ride</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>JOKE</li>
</ul>
</div>

<script src="<php echo 
get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jstree/dist/jstree.min.js';?>"></script>

<script>    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#data').jstree({"plugin":["checkbox"]}); });</script>
```

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but I don't think you are close. Your PHP tags are wrong, you have no head or body elements in your html despite having title and link elements, you're using jQuery but not loading it and and you're using `$` instead of `jQuery` anyway. Is this even running in a WordPress context? Where is this code going?

Comment: All good I found the wrong code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Basically jquery was missing through

```
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

and the wrong PHP tags. Thanks for that.
You can find the full code below.

```
<title> Hi all</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().
'/js/jstree/dist/themes/default/style.min.css';?>" />
<div id="data">
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three
    <ul>
        <li>Bike</li>
        <li>Ride</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>JOKE</li>
</ul>
</div>
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script src="<?php echo 
get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jstree/dist/jstree.min.js';?>"></script>

<script src="<?php echo 
get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jstree/dist/tree.js';?>"></script>
```